# Argument Type is not CLS-compliant...class structure

Tags: c#

I have a class as follows...The idea is to do some logic processing and return a read only object.

```
public class Test
{
    public object property1 { get; private set; }
    public string property2 { get; private set; }


    private Test(){}

    public static Test GetTest(XDocument document)
    {
        if (document== null)
            return null;

        return new Test 
        {
            property1 = l_document.Element("something").value,
            property2 = l_document.Element("anotherthing").value,
        };
    }
}
```

If I use the above test object as paramerter in a function, I get a message Argument Type is not CLS-compliant... Any suggestions?
Any other way I can achieve a read only object?

Thanks,
Kamar

Comment: Post the actual code that produces the message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: (Removed previous answer.)

Having tried this myself, I strongly suspect that it's just a matter of you not putting `[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]` in the assembly declaring the `Test` class. Do that, and all should be peachy.

Comment: Links to the Microsoft discussion about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx and another article http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Making-Your-Code-CLS-Compliant/.  I agree with Jon as the only thing I can see that is not CLS compliant possibly is the XDocument usage.

Comment: @ImperialLion: No, I think it's just the test assembly.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood where the error is.  Yes not marking the assembly as being compliant would cause that problem as well.  I was thinking that he was getting an error that the class itself was non-compliant which is a problem I've run into many times.

Comment: @ImperialLion: The class itself *isn't* compliant - simply because it hasn't asserted that it thinks it is :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Right, but there is nothing in the class keeping it from being compliant once it is marked as being so.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Why do we have to do add [assembly:CLSCompliant(true)] in the first place?

Comment: @Kamar: To specify that you want to claim everything in the assembly *is* CLS compliant.